# How do I get the Walkies achievement?

Tags: achievements, jetpack-joyride

Jetpack joyride has a new Achievement based on Flash. How can I get Walkies? The description says:

> Take Flash on a 10KM Walk

Does this mean I have to travel 10KM in a single run with Flash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you have to own Flash; he's the robot Dog that costs 8,500 coins in the Gadgets menu. The achievement is only possible with Flash equipped to a Gadget slot.

All you have to do is travel 10,000 meters **cumulative** with Flash equipped. You don't have to reach 10,000 meters in one run, multiple runs still count toward the total. After you've gained 10km in travel with Flash you'll be awarded the achievement upon your death.

There's a counter in My Profile under Gadgets that lists "Total Distance run by dog"; this is the count that matters. The counter appears to go up whenever *Flash* runs, not Barry. I'm not sure if it goes up when Flash jumps yet.

Comment: Small side note coming from JJ Classic: The counter only goes up when in classic mode. At least in Chinese New Year Event mode it does not increase

Answer (score 3):

I just got this without walking too much myself.  I think 10000 meters is just for the dog.  Look in "My Profile" under "Total Distance Run By Dog", you will get the achievement when that reaches 10000M.

Comment: So there is an entry in My Profile, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

After you accumulate Flash the third last gadget you have to travel 10,000km (total) with him equipped and you will get it. Flash costs 8,500.

Answer (score 1):

To get the "Walkies" achievement you must purchase Flash in the gadgets section, and then walk a total of 10km. It does not have to be in one round/game.

Comment: You don't have to "walk" 10km - you simply have to cover a distance of 10km cumulatively while having Flash equiped.